# Assign a Class to the Current "Tag" for Formatting

Tags: css, tags, menus, filters, select

Essentially what I am hoping to replicate is something like the "current-menu-item" class that is applied to WP Menus.

My client is wanting to use Tags as a sub-nav, and I've managed to get the tags for the category output as an unordered list, but now if someone selects the tag "Tag One", I'd like to have that particular tag to highlight as the currently selected Tag.

It would be extra super cool if this could also work with the output generated by "the_tags" attached to the post as well.

I hope this makes sense, and thanks!

Cheers,
John

Comment: it could help if you can post the code of 'the tags for the category output as an unordered list'; general idea: to use `if(is_tag('this-tag') echo 'current';` with each element.

Comment: `the_tags()` only returns the tags this post is attached to, so every tag there is a current tag, no?

Comment: @JanFabry Should be an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Add something like this to the functions file:

```
function current_tag($tags) {
    global $wp_query;
    $cid = $wp_query->query_vars['cat'];
    foreach($tags as $tag) {
        // match tagid to $cid
    }
} 
add_filter( 'get_the_tags', 'current_tag');
```

This won't work by itself, but it will be a good start for getting the right information to the right place.