# Highlight current tag using get_tags()

Tags: tags, archives

I'm nearly there with this, but I need to highlight the current tag link/archive being viewed:

```
<ul id="blog-tags">
            <?php 
            $tags = get_tags();
            if ($tags) {
                foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                    echo '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tag->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tag->name.'</a></li>';
                }
            }
             ?>
        </ul>
```

I'd like to apply `<li class="active-tag">` to the list item that contains the active tag in the code above - can anyone help me with that please?

Many thanks

Osu

Comment: Look at this thread : [questions/16816](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16816/assign-a-class-to-the-current-tag-for-formatting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare `$tag->term_id`  with the value from `get_queried_object_id()`. You have to cast the former to integer, because it is provided as a string for no good reason.

```
<ul id="blog-tags">
<?php
$tags = get_tags();
if ( $tags ) {
    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
        echo '<li>';

        if ( (int) $tag->term_id === get_queried_object_id() )
            echo "<b>$tag->name</b>";
        else
            printf(
                '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>',
                get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ),
                $tag->name
            );

        echo '</li>';
    }
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice, fav it now